# Approximative extension of the autohomeomorphism of the complement of the trivial knot?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, 3-manifolds, homeomorphism

Let $S^1\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be the unit circle and suppose $h\colon \mathbb{R}^3\setminus S^1\to \mathbb{R}^3\setminus S^1$ is a homeomorphism. Clearly it might be that $h$ cannot be extended to $S^1$. But can it be "extended" in an approximative way? More precisely:

Given an $\varepsilon>0$, does there exist a homeomorphism $\hat h\colon\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\hat h(x)=h(x)$ for all $x$ with $d(x,S^1)>\varepsilon$.

---

Below are my incomplete thoughts on this so far.

Here is one way I think this could be proved. [Morton Brown has proved](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183523455) the following generalization of the Jordan-Schönflies theorem: If $f\colon S^2\times[0,1]\to S^3$ is an embedding, then the components of $S^3\setminus f[S^2\times\{\frac{1}{2}\}]$ are topological $3$-cells. SUPPOSE this result was proved for $S^2$ replaced by the standard torus, i.e. saying that "if $g\colon T^2\times [0,1]\to S^3$ is an embedding, then the complements of $g[T^2\times\{\frac{1}{2}\}]$ are solid tori". Then we can apply this theorem to the torus $\{x\mid \varepsilon/2<d(x,S^1)<2\varepsilon\}$ and conclude that the "inside" of $h[\{x\mid d(x,S^1)=\varepsilon\}]$ is homeomorphic to a torus.

BUT I haven't found this generalization of this Brown's theorem. Nor any version of Jordan-Schönflies theorem or Jordan-Brouwer Separation Theorem that I have found seems to help (at least I don't see how).

Or perhaps someone can cook-up an argument using Dehn's surgery?

Comment: "...then ONE of the complements is a standard torus", I assume you mean. (This is true smoothly, I'm sure it's true in your topologically flat setting as well; see Hatcher's 3-manifold notes for a proof in the smooth case.) One complement could be knotted.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I will look into it. Indeed, the torus can be knotted in general (not in my case I think).

Comment: I do not assume flatness explicitly, but I suppose that by the triangulation results by Moise I can assume that the homeomorphism is piecewice linear (or smooth) (but the derivatives explode as we appriach $S^1$)

Comment: The answer to my question seems to be Exercise 3 on page 9 of Hatcher's 3-manifold notes  (so thanks!) and it says that it is a theorem of Alexander without reference. Do you @MikeMiller , or someone, have reference?

Comment: I did not see originally that your circle is the unit circle, I agree both sides are unknotted in your case. For a reference, I get from [this](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Embeddings_in_Euclidean_space:_an_introduction_to_their_classification) Manifold Atlas page: J. W. Alexander, On the subdivision of 3-space by polyhedron, Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. USA, 10, (1924) 6–8.